# When and where was the non-deponent form of verb "miror" used?

Tags: language-evolution, deponent-verbs

I've heard that deponent verb "miror" also had a non-deponent form. As far as I know it was in medieval Latin. So is it true? When exactly was the verb "mirare" used? Was it used everywhere, or was it a regionalism? And how did the meaning differ from the deponent form?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Lewis & Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dmiro) entry for *miro* indicates that it is an “ante-classical form of miror”. Combining the examples in this entry with those found in [An Etymological Analysis of Latin Verbs](https://books.google.com/books?id=NxVgAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA111&lpg=PA111&dq=%22aut+ambos+mira%22&source=bl&ots=qFYPLB0fdr&sig=ZPKRjlnW3AWqSlimHVPjtOT3vHg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjJvY2E6Y7LAhVG8j4KHfPcDhIQ6AEIITAB#v=onepage&q=%22aut%20ambos%20mira%22&f=false), I have found the following authors who use the active form instead of the deponent:

1. Varro (d. 27 BC)

   > Hospes, quid miras nummo curare Serapim?

   and

   > Aut ambos mira aut noli mirare de eodem
2. Pomponius (d. AD 138)

   > Si studium mirabis diu...

The entry in [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/miro#Latin), however, informs us that it is “especially used in late or vulgar Latin”.

I have been unable to locate examples of this usage in medieval Latin, however.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: thanks for the formatting help. I accepted your edits, but as a quick aside quotations always outside the period are standard U.S. usage :)